# Zend Nginx routes are blank pages with no errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx

Recently moved a site over from a LAMP to a LEMP setup and I'm having trouble as the main site page comes up fine but all the sub page routes are just blank white pages with no errors being output.

So the root www.mysite.com works, but www.mysite.com/login or www.mysite.com/signup does not.  Just a blank white page.

I've looked at the /var/log/nginx/error.log and have enabled errors by adding...

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

...in my index.php, which I'm not sure does anything with Nginx.  I'm kind of a noob to Nginx.

UPDATE:

So it seems the htaccess rules aren't recognized by NginX:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::^B$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

How can I get NginX to operate with these rules?

Comment: try adding `fastcgi_intercept_errors on` to your nginx config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try setting `display_errors = On` in the php.ini in case it's not calling the index.php?

Also, have you got your NginX `rewrite / /index.php;` in place for the site?

See [Magento - Wiki - Configuring nginx for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento)

Comment: It seems the issue is that NginX doesn't recognize my htaccess rules...  How / where can I convert these to work?

Comment: Unfortunately NginX doesn't use .htaccess files. So you'll need to convert your current rules. Maybe try something like [a htaccess converter](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess)?
By the way, all of these new rules need to go in to the site definition file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default is the default one).